# How do I avoid multiple jquery dropdown boxes interfering with eachother

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I need to know how to alter my code to have multiple dropdowns work on the same page. The number of dropdowns on the page will vary because they are dynamically created from a database. Their function is provided by jquery. I would like each dropdown to work independently from the others.

Code is below but not sure if I should post eh css as it's really long so here is the link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pj5rE/

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper-demo">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1">Dropdown
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-demo">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1">Dropdown
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
    function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            event.stopPropagation();
        }); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );
        $(document).click(function() {
            // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-2').removeClass('active');
        });

});
```

I'm pretty new to programming and javascript so I hope that all made sense. Help in full or in part is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can't have id's with the same value, they need to be unique.  Also, I'm not sure if I understand the desired behavior.  Do you want all of the dropdowns to become active by clicking any other dropdown, or are you simply trying to set the individual behavior for all dropdowns.  Can you please qualify that?

Comment: I would like each individual dropdown to act independently of the others. I realize now the id's need to be different, but then how do I get them all to work since it seems like right now the javascript is calling the dropdown by it's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to prototype this, but based on what you're saying your desired behavior is, try this:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper-demo">
    <div class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1">Dropdown
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-demo">
    <div class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1">Dropdown
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function() {

        $('div.wrapper-dropdown-2').click(function(e) {  
            e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).hasClass('active'))
            {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
            else
            {  
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }          
    });
});
```

See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pj5rE/4/

Comment: Thank you. This works like I had intended. The prototype stuff was in there from the tutorial I was following.